# ember's dependency on jQuery

Tags: ember.js

I've noticed that emberjs states a dependency to the 1.9.x family of jQuery in it's `composer.json` and `bower.json` files. I'd be interested in pushing upward and onward to later versions of jQuery but wasn't sure if that was just asking for trouble.

A few searches I did before asking this question indicated that ember's use of jQuery is only in the View and I did hear a few people state that they *were* using ember with jQuery 2.x ... all of this makes me encouraged to think it would work but as I'm such a newbie I really can't afford to run into problems only to be plagued with the thought ... maybe this is because I'm using the wrong version of jQuery. ;^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've noticed that emberjs states a dependency to the 1.9.x family of jQuery in it's composer.json and bower.json files. I'd be interested in pushing upward and onward to later versions of jQuery but wasn't sure if that was just asking for trouble.

I guess you do ask for some trouble :)

> A few searches I did before asking this question indicated that ember's use of jQuery is only in the View and I did hear a few people state that they were using ember with jQuery 2.x ... all of this makes me encouraged to think it would work but as I'm such a newbie I really can't afford to run into problems only to be plagued with the thought ... maybe this is because I'm using the wrong version of jQuery. ;^)

I can't lamentably remember the title of the question asked here on SO in which a dev was using jQuery 2.x and after I reproduced his use case in a jsbin using version 1.9.x fixed the problem.

So, IMHO if you don't need features only available in jQuery 2.x you should stick to the recommend version ember is using.

Hope it helps.

*P.D. I'll try to find the thread I was talking about and update my answer...*